# prove the convergence sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove that the sequence is convergent?

${a_{n+2} = {\sqrt{a_{n+1}} + \sqrt{a_{n}}}}$  , where $a_{1}=1$ and $a_{2}$ is a positive number.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you experimented with, say, $a_2 = 4$ to see what happens, and with $a_2 = 1/4$? A numerical experiment may lead to some enlightenment.

Comment: Assuming that the sequence converges, what would the limit be? Use that value as lower or upper bound if you can prove that the sequence is (eventually) monotonic.

Comment: Try monotonic convergent theorem to show the sequence is convergent, and then let $n \to \infty$ on both sides of the recursive formula.

Comment: For instance, we have $$2\sqrt{\min(a_{n-1}, a_{n-2})}\leq a_n \leq 2\sqrt{\max(a_{n-1}, a_{n-2})}$$ which should be of some use.

Comment: If the sequence converges to $a$, then $a$ must satisfy $a=2\sqrt{a}$, and the only positive number that satisfies this equation is $a=4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We observe that for every $n \geq 3$, $a_n > 1$.

We first show $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.
If $0 < a_2 \leq 4$, then $a_3 = 1 + \sqrt{4} < 4$, $a_4 = \sqrt{a_2} + \sqrt{a_3} < 2 + 2 = 4$, and so on, we can show each $a_n < 4$.
If $a_2 > 4$, then $a_3 = 1 + \sqrt{a_2} < 2a_2 + 2a_2 = 4a_2, a_4 = \sqrt{a_3} + \sqrt{a_2} < \sqrt{4a_2} + \sqrt{4a_2} = 4\sqrt{a_2} < 4a_2$, and so on, we can show each $a_n < 4a_2$.

Next we show $\{a_n\}$ is monotonic. Let $x_0$ be the positive root of the equation $1 + \sqrt{x} = x$.

If $0 < a_2 \leq x_0$, then $a_3 - a_2 = 1 + \sqrt{a_2} - a_2 > 0, a_4 - a_3 = \sqrt{a_3} - \sqrt{a_1} > 0$, therefore, $a_5 - a_4 = \sqrt{a_4} - \sqrt{a_2} > \sqrt{a_3} - \sqrt{a_2} > 0$. In general, we can show recursively, $a_{n + 1} - a_n = \sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a_{n - 2}} > \sqrt{a_{n - 1}} - \sqrt{a_{n - 2}} > 0$. Hence the sequence is monotonically increasing.

If $a_2 > x_0$, we clearly have $a_3 < a_2$ but $a_4 > a_3$.

Now if $a_5 \geq a_4$, then as the previous argument, we can show $\{a_n\}$ is increasing from $n = 3$. If $a_5 < a_4$, note that if there exists some integer $N$ such that $a_N \leq (\geq) a_{N + 1}, a_N \leq (\geq) a_{N + 2}$, then in the same manner as preceding argument, we have $a_N \leq (\geq) a_{N + 2} \leq (\geq) a_{N + 3} \leq (\geq) \cdots$; i.e., the sequence is eventually monotonic. If such $N$ doesn't exist, then the sequence goes like this:
$$a_1 < a_2 > a_3 < a_4 > a_5 < a_6 > a_7 < \cdots.$$
In other words, every even term is a local maximum and every odd term is a local minimum.

For any $k > 1$,
$$a_{2k + 2} = \sqrt{a_{2k + 1}} + \sqrt{a_{2k}} > a_{2k + 1} = \sqrt{a_{2k}} + \sqrt{a_{2k - 1}}$$
showing $a_{2k + 1} > a_{2k - 1}$, that is, the odd subsequence $\{a_{2k - 1}\}_{k \geq 1}$ is strictly increasing, hence converge to some limit $\alpha$.

Similarly, for any $k > 1$, 
$$a_{2k + 3} = \sqrt{a_{2k + 2}} + \sqrt{a_{2k + 1}} < a_{2k + 2} = \sqrt{a_{2k + 1}} + \sqrt{a_{2k}}$$
showing $a_{2k + 2} < a_{2k}$, that is, the even subsequence $\{a_{2k}\}_{k \geq 1}$ is strictly decreasing, hence converge to some limit $\beta$.

In $a_{2k} = \sqrt{a_{2k - 1}} + \sqrt{a_{2k - 2}}$, let $k \to \infty$, we have
$$\beta = \sqrt{\alpha} + \sqrt{\beta}.$$
In $a_{2k + 1} = \sqrt{a_{2k}} + \sqrt{a_{2k - 1}}$, let $k \to \infty$, we have 
$$\alpha = \sqrt{\beta} + \sqrt{\alpha}.$$

Therefore, $\alpha = \beta$, implying the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.